# Is it possible to use Audit.Net with httpClient to capture external requests

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, audit.net

Using Audit.Net is it possible to create an audit scope for httpClient requests, in a similar way to the MVC.Core or WebAPI.Core Middleware?

I've tried something like this but not having much success, generally it'll timeout the app.

```
AuditScope scope = null;
try {
 using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient) {

  scope = await AuditScope.CreateAsync("",() => client)
  // code to initialise the Httpclient
 }
}
finally {
 await scope.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only option to hook into the `HttpClient` is to use a custom `HttpClientHandler` so you can intercept the rest calls.

Just as an example:

```
public class AuditClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var options = new AuditScopeOptions()
        {
            EventType = $"{request.Method.Method} {request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri}",
            CreationPolicy = EventCreationPolicy.InsertOnStartReplaceOnEnd,
            ExtraFields = new
            {
                request = GetRequestAudit(request)
            }
        };
        using (var scope = AuditScope.Create(options))
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            scope.SetCustomField("response", GetResponseAudit(response));
            return response;
        } 
    }
}
```

> I've used the `InsertOnStartReplaceOnEnd` creation policy, so the request is saved before it's sent to the server, and the response is added to the event and saved afterwards.
>
> The implementation of `GetRequestAudit` / `GetResponseAudit` is up to you, just return an object (that can be serialized) with the information you want to log.

So each time you need to audit an `HttpClient` instance, you need to pass the handler to its constructor:

```
var cli = new HttpClient(new AuditClientHandler());
var response = await cli.GetAsync("http://google.com");
```

Anyway I will evaluate providing a new library (`Audit.HttpClient`?) with a configurable Handler so the implementation could be cleaner.

## Update

You can now use the Audit.HttpClient extension for a cleaner implementation. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.HttpClient/README.md)

Comment: The new extension implementation will be tracked [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/221)